# How to Activate a Word document?

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am creating word document from c# windows application. but Word document is getting minimized even though i used the Activate() method to activate the document.

(it is working fine when debugging but in release version document getting minimized)

How I Can Make the document active one???

Thanks in advance.

my code is almost like this

> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
>   document;
>
> object objFileName = locationOfFile; 
>   object objTrueValue = true;  object
>   objMissing = Type.Missing;
>
> document =
>   application.Documents.Open(ref
>   objFileName, ref  objMissing, ref
>   objTrueValue,
>                       ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref
>   objMissing, ref objMissing,
>                       ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref
>   objMissing, ref objMissing,
>                       ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing);
>
> document.Activate();

Comment: It should only get minimized if you tell the Word application to minimize. Can you show the code?

Comment: @ GolezTrol,it is working fine when debugging but in release version document getting minimized

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I focus on a Word document I just opened through interop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536415/how-can-i-focus-on-a-word-document-i-just-opened-through-interop)

Answer (score 0):

It is working for both.

```
document = application.Documents.Open(@"\Docu.docx", ReadOnly: false, Visible: true );
```

set the Visible:true, Document.Activate(); is not required.

It would be help more if you show your code.