# How can I focus on a Word document I just opened through interop?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am writing a simple Word Interop application which open a .doc file in background, changes bookmarks content, then make it visible to the user :

```
var App = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

var ParTemplate = (object)Template;
var ParVisible = (object)false;

var Doc = App.Documents.Open(
    FileName: ref ParTemplate, // Template
    ConfirmConversions: ref missing,
    ReadOnly: ref missing,
    ...

Doc.Activate();

Doc.SetBookmarkValue("IssueNumber", TheIssue.IssueNo);
Doc.SetBookmarkValue("Title", TheIssue.Title);
...

App.Visible = true;
App.WindowState = WdWindowState.wdWindowStateNormal;
```

Actually, the Word application appears in the task tray, and the user has to switch to it manually.

What is the best way to make my application focus on the opened Word document ?

Comment: C# 4 supports optional parameters, so you don't need the `ref missing`s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this     `App.Activate();` instead of `Doc.Activate()`.

Comment: I did not replace Doc.Activate(), because I need it (it is required by the TypeText I am using in the SetBookmarkValue extension method). I did put App.Activate() after App.Visible = true and it works the way I expected. Thanks !

Comment: I edited the post to add a App.WindowState = WdWindowState.wdWindowStateNormal I forgot. Without this, the application is activated, but as a icon in the task bar.